# When I delete a single record into a template all records are deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models ***child*** and ***academy*** by which these two models have relationship to each other

here is child models

```
from django.db import models
class Child_detail(models.Model):
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Tribe = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Firstname
```

And here is academy model

```
from django.db import models
from child.models import Child_detail
class Academic(models.Model):
    Student_name = models.ForeignKey(Child_detail,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    Class = models.CharField(max_length =  50)
    Average_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_name)
```

Here is my views.py file that contain ***delete*** functionality,instead of delete a single academy record of that specific child it delete all academic details of that specific child

```
def delete_academy(request,pk):
    child=get_object_or_404(Child_detail,pk=pk)
    academy=Academic.objects.filter(Student_name=child)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        academy.delete()
        return redirect('more',pk=pk)  
    context={
        'child':child,
        #'form':form
    }     
    return render(request,'functionality/more/academy/delete.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You select **all** the academies of that child:

```
academy=Academic.objects.filter(Student_name=child)
```

Then you delete them all

```
academy.delete()
```

Instead, you should provide which academy you want to remove in the filter method.

```
academy=Academic.objects.filter(Student_name=child, Class="foo")
```

If you want to remove the first result:

```
academy[0].delete()
```

Comment: Thanks bro it works,but what ```Class="foo"``` mean?

Comment: Just put in the name of the Academic Class you want to remove from that child

Comment: Hello bro i am asking what if it was edit functionality i want to implement by use the same example...@ToTheMax